# Local Bot for Skype for business using Microsoft bot framework

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, skype-for-business

I have created a bot using the bot framework, integrated LUIS and deployed it to Azure. I want to deploy it to Skype for Business but not to everyone, just to test it with my personal account first. Is this possible? (I'm not a tenant administrator)

[This](https://skypeappregistration.azurewebsites.net/bot/29415286-5a43-4a00-9dc5-bcbc2ce1f59e) procedure is to add the bot to everyone which is not what I want for now.

Comment: You must be a tenant admin to configure bots on Skype for Business.

Comment: Even for a local bot?

Comment: So basically the bot can't be tested on skype for business without actually registering the bot for everyone?

Comment: you would need a O365 tenant admin to enable your bot for Skype for Business channel via PowerShell scripting as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/channel-connect-skypeforbusiness